# Question about finding constants for which a function is a solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^{3/4}$. Find values for the constants $a > 0$ and $b$ for which $x(t) = (at)^b$ is a solution to the ODE for $t >0$.

I'm pretty sure I'm making a mistake somewhere or missing something because I've been messing with algebra for a while and nothing of what I've gotten looks right.

I first differentiated the given function and got $a^bbt^{b-1}$ and plugged in both the derivative and $x(t)$ into the ODE. I first tried to solve for a and got $a = b^{-4/b}t^{\frac{4}{b-1}}$ but then I realized since a and b are constant and that's a function of t it can't be the answer. I then tried to solve for t and got $t = (b^4a^b)^{1/4-b}$ which I plugged back into the ODE with $x(t)$ and $dx/dt$ substituted in and got $a = b^{2/(b(3b-13)}$ but something tells me I perhaps shouldn't have substituted the t in and that that's still not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{-3/4}dx=dt\implies \dfrac{1}{-3/4+1}x^{-3/4+1}=t+c \implies 4x^{1/4}=t+c$$
$$\implies x(t)=\dfrac{(t+c)^4}{4^4}$$

Comparision with your expression is possible if we set $c=0$

$$\implies x(t)=\left[\dfrac{1}{4}t\right]^4.$$
Then $a=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $b=4$.